# Installing local Node.js project globally

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, global

I'm trying to install my custom made project globally across my system so I can call it anywhere in my computer from the cmd, but it doesn't quite work.
I tried:

```
npm install -g .
```

and more but I can't remember. This is my package.json:

```json
...
"name": "nodejs-insta-reddit-cli",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./build/index.js",
  "bin": {
    "instapostwouter": "./build/index.js"
  },
...
```

The reason the main path is in `./build/index.js` is because I'm using typescript.

So my question is: How would I install my project globally so that I can use it on my workstation in any directory?

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link.html you need to use the npm link for that purpose.

Comment: When I run `npm link` in my project directory, It seems to install it but I still can't access `instapostwouter`.

Comment: and how are you trying to access it ?

Comment: by typing `instapostwouter` in a restarted cmd in Administrator Mode.

Comment: is that a cli module ?

Comment: you will need a folder named bin. rename the folder build to bin and respective paths.

Comment: or you can expose the main file to in the bin folder and other files in build or lib folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `npm link` in the directory of local module you want to access globally.

Then you add it using `npm link package_name`.

OR you can publish the module (Private or Public) and use install it globally and use it.

More information on [Npm Link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link.html)

NOTE: if you are working with cli package then make sure you have a bin folder and entry inside the package.json file.

Comment: I created `bin` folder and put `index.js` in there and then changed the path `bin` (in package.json) to `./bin/index.js`. Then I did `npm link` and `npm link instapostwouter`. But when I tried to run `instapostwouter` in a cmd, it still didn't work: `'instapostwouter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: I have tried restarting my command prompt and launching the commands in administrator mode but nothing seems to work.. I have never gotten this to work in any project ever so I really don't know what the problem is.

Comment: its quite odd behavior try updating the node js to LTS.

Comment: Okay I'm getting further. Now when I run `instapostwouter` I get the following popup: https://imgur.com/a/ZX8m1aY

Comment: This is the code that contains line 155: https://www.codepile.net/pile/r93qPZK4

Comment: well that seem to be another error you can post another question. (tip: you are using typescript code  make sure you transpile it into native js code before running the link command.)

Comment: Yes I do `npx tsc` and then copy the index.js file in the bin folder.